# How to install VSTS sync migration tool offline?

Tags: azure-devops

I have installed chocolate offline but when I try to install vsts sync migration tool using power shell proxy is blocking. How can I install sync migration toll offline? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean [Migration Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration), you can download the latest release from GitHub and unzip it directly:

https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/releases